# Unix Logger logs fetching using grep

Tags: unix, grep

How to use grep command to fetch logs based on hours ? I want to fetch logs from say 20:00 hours to 23:00 hours.

```
[1/10/16 23:55:33:018 PST] 00000057 ServerObj E   SECJ0373E: Exception message
          at                             com.own.ws.wim.util.UniqueNameHelper.formatUniqueName(UniqueNameHelper.java:102)
          at com.own.ws.wim.ProfileManager.getImpl(ProfileManager.java:1569)
```

Please help me out, I am beginner to unix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will get logs on the day shown from 20:00 to 22:59

```
grep '^\[1/10/16 2[012]:'
```

How it works

- `^`  anchor to start of line so only matches at start of line
- `\[` literally match a square bracket.  Without the `\` square bracket is special in regexp
- `[012]` match a digit 0 or 1 or 2

Comment: Its working fine. I was wondering if it can fetch 1/10/16 17:00 to 1/11/16 5:30.

Comment: It can select the range you suggest but it would be a long regexp with the alternation ``|`` operator.    Probably easier to select by day to temp files and then repeat a grep to get the time range required.  I wouldn't use grep for this task, I'd use a scripting language such as perl or python

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$ egrep '^\[[0-9/]+ 2[0-2]:' log_file
```